# Passing argument from fragment to activity using SafeArgs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-safe-args, android-navigation-graph

Using navigation graph, when i navigate from fragment to activity and also passing argument using safeargs, in activity, I cannot get argument. How can I get argument passing from fragment???

In fragment, I can get argument by `getArgument()` function, but not in activity.

In fragment I switch to another activity by:

```
findNavController().navigate(AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBActivity(1)
```

and in B activity get argument in onCreate by :

```
val args = BActivityArgs.fromBundle(savedInstanceState!!)
```

but my app crash immediately.

Comment: Plese show us what have you tried?

Comment: Please add your source code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out the Android Doc :-

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#java

Send Data

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
EditText amountTv = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTv.getText().toString());
ConfirmationAction action =
       SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction()
action.setAmount(amount)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
}
```

Get Data :-

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount);
int amount = ConfirmationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getAmount();
tv.setText(amount + "")
}
```

Comment: getArguments() can only get argument in fragment. I want to get argument in activity.

Comment: I have read your link and I can get the argument by : `val args : BActivityArgs by navArgs()` outside onCreate. Thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is **not** an answer to your question. As you point out: you cannot use `getArguments()` in your `Activity`, you can only do that in a fragment. However, in an activity you can get the data like this (java syntax):

```
String aField = BActivityArgs.fromBundle(getIntent().getExtras()).getAField()
```

So, just replace `getArguments()` with `getIntent().getExtras()` if you have an `Activity` on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

```java
BActivityArgs.fromBundle(getIntent().getExtras()).getAField();
```

Work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

- As stated in the official documentation [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) :

> The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. In an app with multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation graph

- A solution might be: rethink if the activity could be converted to a Fragment and then the newly created Fragment could be handled by the same Navigation Component. Thus allowing you to use the normal SafeArgs syntax to pass and retrieve data.
- If you are still having problems with the SafeArgs plugin, I would highly recommend this medium article by the official Android team, [HERE](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigating-with-safeargs-bf26c17b1269)